# Simple Audio Play Stop In Android

Tags: java, android, audio

I am Beginer in Android.

I want To create an  app

When Clicking an Image(Play button Image) a MP3 file starts to play and image chnage to another image(Pause Button image) and Map3 Stops

How to create this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a simple example to start, stop and pause the audio play.

Drag three buttons from pallete to start, stop and pause the audio play. Now the xml file will look like this:

File: activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"  
        android:text="Audio Controller" />  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button1"  
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"  
        android:text="start" />  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button2"  
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"  
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"  
        android:text="pause" />  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button3"  
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"  
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"  
        android:text="stop" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity class

Let's write the code to start, pause and stop the audio player.

File: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.audioplay;  

import android.media.MediaPlayer;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.os.Environment;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    Button start,pause,stop;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);  
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);  
        //creating media player  
        final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();  
        try{  
                //you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3  
        mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Music/maine.mp3");  

        mp.prepare();  
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mp.start();  
            }  
        });  
        pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mp.pause();  
            }  
        });  
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mp.stop();  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
 
 start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);  
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3); 

Errors in 3 lines
"button1 cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: have you created `activity_main` xml in layout folder?

Comment: Ya, I created, UI Shows Correctly, 3 buttons are visible

Comment: what is name of that xml file?

Comment: @JaseelMuhammed I edited my answer above.\ Once try it by renaming `MainActivity.java` to `activity_main.xml`

Comment: ...
public static final int useLogo=0x7f050003;
public static final int withText=0x7f05000c;
public static int button1;
}
...

same problem

Comment: Once clean your project or else check under res folder is there any errors?